# How to get the Screen Coordinates anywhere in the phone Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to find the coordinates for the screen while I'm outside of the app. I found a way to get the coordinates inside the app by this way.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  GlobalKey key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Material(
        child: Listener(
          child: SizedBox.expand(
            key: key,
            child: GestureDetector(

              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                print(details.globalPosition);
              },

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is the "App" screen. when dragged a area it will show the position in the terminal as below]

```
I/flutter ( 9587): Offset(149.4, 182.0)
I/flutter ( 9587): Offset(148.6, 182.8)
I/flutter ( 9587): Offset(148.6, 183.4)
```

This obviously works inside the app. Is there a way to know the same positions **outside** of the app. That means like Even shows the location when dragged in the home screen or any other app [image]

Is the way to do it by creating a background service? if so How do you get the app screen(1st picture) and phone screen meaning working any where on the phone(2nd image) to work together?

Edit: Is there a way to get the pointer location data from settings > Developer options > Input > Pointer location

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you find any solution for this, I need the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try pyautogui. position but this work only for your desktop screen, but if you have an Android studio you can try it and after this, you can calculate the position of your android screen you need not the screen resolution of your desktop, and if you put an Android emulation to corner you can easily calculate with this math operation 1:x(times2. Or if you have only mobile devices you can try some apps in PlayStore

```
import time
import pyautugui as pg
time.sleep(5)
print(pg.position())
```

Comment: pyautogui is for desktops. I'm trying to get it for a mobile app(flutter). I'm looking for a way to get it not from an app from playstore. Thanks tho.

Comment: OK but I do not know how this will work because Android does not like a programming language Trust me I have tried a download song with a new pipe and it does not work but I am only a beginner so maybe some way to get it to exist.